# FacebookforDrupal Publish to stream isnt working?

Tags: 7, social-network, nodes

I am trying to publish a node onto facebook. Below is my code. In hook_nodeapi(), I have placed a dpm("test") but it isnt showing. I am assuming that this function is not called at all?

```
function fb_stream_ext_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  dpm("test");
  if ($op == 'insert' || $op == 'update') {
    if (isset($node->stream_publish) && $node->stream_publish) {
      $attachment = array(
        'name' => $node->title,
        'href' => url('node/' . $node->nid, array('absolute' => TRUE)),
        'description' => filter_xss($node->teaser, array()),
      );

      /*
        if ($picture = $GLOBALS['user']->picture) {
        $url = url($picture, array('absolute' => TRUE));
        $attachment['media'][] = array(
        'type' => 'image',
        'src' => $url,
        'href' => $url,
        );
        }
      */
      if ($logo_path = theme_get_setting('logo_path')) {
        $url = url($logo_path, array('absolute' => TRUE));
        //dpm($logo_path, "logo_path is $logo_path and url is $url");
        $attachment['media'][] = array(
          'type' => 'image',
          'src' => $url,
          'href' => $url,
        );
      }

      $user_message = t('Check out my latest post on !site...',
                        array('!site' => variable_get('site_name', t('my Drupal for Facebook powered site'))));
      $actions = array();
      $actions[] = array(
        'text' => t('Read More'),
        'href' => url('node/' . $node->nid, array('absolute' => TRUE)),
      );
      fb_stream_publish_dialog(array('message' => $user_message,
                                     'attachment' => $attachment,
                                     'action_links' => $actions,
                               ));
    }
  }

  // Another way to add like button, as part of a node.
  if ($op == 'view' && variable_get('fb_stream_ext_nodeapi_add_like', FALSE)) {
    $url = fb_scrub_urls(url('node/' . $node->nid, array('absolute' => TRUE)));
    $node->content['dff_like'] = array(
      '#value' => "<fb:like href={$url}></fb:like>",
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#prefix' => '<div class="dff_like_wrapper">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );
  }
}
```

Any known solution for this?

Comment: Try placing your dpm("test"); inside if ($op == 'view'){ ... } and then check, if it shows up.

Comment: still nothing. When will this function be called? I read somewhere that hook_nodeapi doesnt work in drupal 7

Comment: can you write the hook for me... just getting confused with the other things in the parenthesis (&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) ... what goes in there is it just $node now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself:

Yes, DrupalForFacebook is out of date. as Dave states [here](http://drupal.org/node/1142518)

hook_nodeapi() is a drupal 6 function, not a drupal 7 function.

The solution is simple: to find a hook function that can replace _nodeapi.

[This function does the exact same thing as hook_nodeapi()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7).

If one changes

> yourHook_nodeapi

to

> yourHook_node_presave($node)

problem is solved.

Thank you for all the help given.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is no hook_nodeapi() for D7. In D7, there are seperate hooks for create, update, view and delete operations. You could use this [Link](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/group/node_api_hooks/7) as a reference. 
You could insert your dpm("test"); inside hook_view() to test it.

Comment: if thats the case, i'm assuming drupalforfacebook is completely out of date?

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: because the above function was copied directly from DrupalForFacebook, in order to post a node as a facebook stream